# using angular, once a selection is made how would you pass the ID using output and then call it in the footer with input

Tags: javascript, html, angular, twitter-bootstrap, api

What I'm trying to do is make a dropdown that calls on the https://swapi.co/ API and once an item is selected it will display the information in the footer component. I'm really new to angular and after spending the last 8 hours trying to learn this I'm kinda lost.

**body.component.html**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
  <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-fill">
      <li class="nav-item col-md-3">
          <a href="/people" routerLink="/people" routerLinkActive="active">People</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item col-md-3">
          <a href="/planets" routerLink="/planets" routerLinkActive="active">Planets</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item col-md-3">
          <a href="/starships" routerLink="/starships" routerLinkActive="active">Starships</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</nav>

<select>
    <option *ngFor="let people of peoples">
      {{people.name}}
    </option>
  </select>
```

**body.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Output, EventEmitter, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { StarwarsService } from '../starwars.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-body',
  templateUrl: './body.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./body.component.scss']
})
export class BodyComponent implements OnInit {

  peoples: unknown[];

  constructor(private starwarsService: StarwarsService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.starwarsService.getPeoples().subscribe(results => {
      console.log(results);
      this.peoples = results.results;
    });
  }
}
```

**footer.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-footer',
  templateUrl: './footer.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./footer.component.scss']
})
export class FooterComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<app-header></app-header>
<hr>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<hr>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Angular-Routing';
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
import { BodyComponent } from './body/body.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './footer/footer.component';
import { PlanetsComponent } from './planets/planets.component';
import { StarshipsComponent } from './starships/starships.component';
import { NotFoundComponent } from './not-found/not-found.component';
import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    BodyComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    PlanetsComponent,
    StarshipsComponent,
    NotFoundComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**starwars.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class StarwarsService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getPeoples() {
    return this.http.get('https://swapi.co/api/people/  ');
  }
  getPeople(id) {
    return this.http.get(`https://swapi.co/api/people/${id}  `);
  }

  getPlanets() {
    return this.http.get('https://swapi.co/api/planets/  ');
  }
  getPlanet(id) {
    return this.http.get(`https://swapi.co/api/planets/${id}  `);
  }

  getStarships() {
    return this.http.get('https://swapi.co/api/starships/  ');
  }
  getStarship(id) {
    return this.http.get(`https://swapi.co/api/starships/${id}  `);
  }
}
```

Comment: Where is your `BodyComponent` in your `app.component.html`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all there is not parent child relationship with your `footer.component` and `body.component` so i will suggest you to use the subject for getting the data from your `body.component` to `footer.component`so here you go

**starwars.service.ts**

```js
// here we are creating a subject and pass the data from body component and subscribe the data from footer component

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Subject, Observable, BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { filter, map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class StarwarsService {
  // subject 
  protected _eventsSubject = new Subject<Event>();

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  broadcast(key: any, value: any) {
    this._eventsSubject.next({ key, value });
  }

  on<T>(key: any): Observable<T> {
    return this._eventsSubject.asObservable()
      .pipe(
        filter(e => e.key === key),
        map(e => e.value)
      );
  }

  getPeoples() {
    return this.http.get('https://swapi.co/api/people/  ');
  }
  getPeople(id) {
    return this.http.get(`https://swapi.co/api/people/${id}  `);
  }

  getPlanets() {
    return this.http.get('https://swapi.co/api/planets/  ');
  }
  getPlanet(id) {
    return this.http.get(`https://swapi.co/api/planets/${id}  `);
  }

  getStarships() {
    return this.http.get('https://swapi.co/api/starships/  ');
  }
  getStarship(id) {
    return this.http.get(`https://swapi.co/api/starships/${id}  `);
  }
}
```

**body.component.ts**

```js
// here we are sending data into our subject 

import { Component, Output, EventEmitter, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { StarwarsService } from '../starwars.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-body',
  templateUrl: './body.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./body.component.scss']
})
export class BodyComponent implements OnInit {

  peoples: unknown[];
  specificPerson: any;
  constructor(private starwarsService: StarwarsService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.starwarsService.getPeoples().subscribe(results => {
      console.log(results);
      this.peoples = results.results;
  }
// this function will triger when you select the value on checkbox
  onPersonChange() {
  // here we are sending the data and our key name is starwarsData so by using 
    this key we can be able to fetch the data in footer component
      this.starwarsService.broadcast('starwarsData', this.specificPerson);
    });

  }
}
```

**body.component.html**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
  <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-fill">
      <li class="nav-item col-md-3">
          <a href="/people" routerLink="/people" routerLinkActive="active">People</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item col-md-3">
          <a href="/planets" routerLink="/planets" routerLinkActive="active">Planets</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item col-md-3">
          <a href="/starships" routerLink="/starships" routerLinkActive="active">Starships</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</nav>

<select ()>
    <option *ngFor="let people of peoples">
      {{people.name}}
    </option>
  </select>

<select  [(ngModel)]="specificPerson"  class="form-control" (change)="onPersonChange()">
      <option *ngFor="let people of peoples" [ngValue]="people.name">{{people.name}}</option>
</select>
```

**Footer.component.ts**

```js
// here we are fetching the data by using our subject 

import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { StarwarsService } from '../starwars.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-footer',
  templateUrl: './footer.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./footer.component.scss']
})
export class FooterComponent implements OnInit {

  personData: any;
  constructor(private starwarsService: StarwarsService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

// "starwarsData" is our key name which have our data 
   this.starwarsService.on('starwarsData').subscribe(response => {
      console.log(response);
      this.personData = response;
   });
  }

}
```

Comment: so what this looks like its doing is making it so the entire array of objects gets passed to the footer and it's not actually displaying any information when a new person is selected. Thank you for the help but I'm still pretty confused on how to accomplish my goal :(

Comment: it's probably an issue with my footer.html tbh so I'm going to continue working on that. thank you so much for the help and any more input on how I could fix the footer would be greatly appreciated

Comment: so you can also show that selected person on footer by using a same approach when you select the person send that data to `brodcaster` and fetch that data from footer same as i show you in answer

Comment: I'm sorry but i'm still confused.

Comment: do you want all the data in footer or specific data?

Comment: i want to display the data of the person who is currently selected in the dropdown

Comment: perfect so in dropdown you have to bind the `change` event so while user cilck on that drop down one function call that function have the specific user data and then you need to `brodcast` the data

Comment: it would be great if you put a drop down code in your question so i will modify the answer and you will get better idea :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure the dropdown code was in the bottom of the body.compponent.html. but im not compltely sure if thats the part that you are asking for. i just did an *ngfor to create the options in it.

Comment: yeah i saw just update my answer i hope it helps you out

Comment: what i did is i smilpy bind the `onchange` event and the get the selected value and pass that value in brodcaster. so you will get the selected person in your footer

Comment: thank you i see what you did there but now im getting a bunch of errors so i guess im just gonna have to troubleshoot a bit. this seems to be the first one. 
   compiler.js:2175 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'select'. ("
  </select>

Comment: import the `FormsModule` in your `app.module` so it looks like this `import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

[...]

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    [...]
    FormsModule
  ],
  [...]
})`

Comment: it one thing after another! Now im getting this error and it looks like the syntax is correct fir the *ngFor so i dont know whats wrong Can't bind to 'ngForPeople' since it isn't a known property of 'option'. ("ect  [(ngModel)]="specificPerson"  class="form-control" (change)="onPersonChange()">

Comment: i saw my code there is one typo i write two times let in `*ngFor` you need to remove one

Comment: now this is happening: Error: Uncaught (in promise): InvalidCharacterError: Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': '()' is not a valid attribute name.

Comment: when i removed the () from the first select in body.component.html it fixed that error but noting moved to the footer when someone was selected

Comment: you need to dubug what it will print when you write the `console.log(this.specificPerson)` inside the `onPersonChange()`

Comment: thank you so much for all of the help. I learned a lot from this and ill be able to take it the rest of the way from here. I really appreciate all of the help you've given me.